# how to use a variable in regex brace in awk?

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I want to use a variable in regex brace
but it seems does not work.

```
$ echo 'abcabcabc' | awk  '{ sub(/(abc){2}/,"XXX");  print }'
XXXabc

# this is not a correct result.
$ echo 'abcabcabc' | awk  '{ i=2; sub(/(abc){i}/,"XXX");  print }'
abcabcabc

$ echo 'abcabcabc' | awk  '{ if (/(abc){3}/)  print "ok" }'
ok

# this does not work correctly.
$ echo 'abcabcabc' | awk  '{ i=3; if (/(abc){i}/)  print "ok" }'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/.../` only supports Regex constants. To pass a variable, you need to use quotes:

```
% echo 'abcabcabc' | awk  '{ i=2; sub("(abc){"i"}","XXX");  print }'
XXXabc
```

- The Regex pattern before the variable is enclosed in quotes, `"(abc){"i`
- Then the variable `i` is used
- The pattern after the variable is again enclosed in quotes

Comment: Thanks heemayl. but there is no way with "/ /" ? do i have to use sub function ? how could i solve second example ?

Comment: @mug896 Check my edits. `/.../` only supports Regex constants.

Comment: my second example does not work with quotes

Comment: @mug896 Use `$0 ~` to match the record with the Regex pattern follows. Here: `echo 'abcabcabc' | awk  '{ i=3; if ($0 ~ "(abc){"i"}")  print "ok" }'`

Comment: I see. it works correctly with "$0 ~"

Comment: _To pass a variable, you need to use quotes_ - That's a GNU `awk` extension.  `mawk` and BSD `awk` don't support it.